# Laravel Component does not work on the hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-components

I have created a Laravel Component and it works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy the project to the hosting it stops working there and the error `Undefined variable $navbar` occurs.

`app\View\Components`

```
class navbar extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public $navbar = [])
    {
        $this->navbar = config('navbar');
    }
    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.navbar');
    }
}
```

When I use the component `<x-navbar ></x-navbar>` an error occurs, but if I add the attribute `<x-navbar :navbar="config('navbar')"></x- navbar>` the error disappears.

I have a feeling that the component class is ignored on the hosting, since even `dd('test')` does not work if it is added to `__construct`. There are no such problems on the local machine.

The project was deployed on [www.hostinger.com](http://www.hostinger.com) according to their [instructions](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/6152127-how-to-deploy-laravel-8-at-hostinger).

Comment: Is your file named `Navbar.php` or `navbar.php`?

Comment: @ceejayoz `navbar.php`. I created it with `php artisan make:component navbar` and everything works on the local machine.

Comment: Try renaming the file to `Navbar.php` and the class to `Navbar`.

Comment: @ceejayoz It didn't help. Directly on the server created a new component with a capital letter.

Comment: What do you mean "directly on the server" and "new component"? I'm not asking you to rerun the Artisan command, just rename the file/class. You'll note in all the examples at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade the components are `Cased` `Like` `This`; this is standard for Laravel. I strongly suspect you've moved from a case-insensitive OS like Windows to a case-sensitive one like Linux on the server, and that `<x-navbar>` looks for `Navbar`, not `navbar`.

Comment: @ceejayoz I ran the `php artisan make:component Navbar` command on the server via SSH, but I also manually renamed this file and that didn't help.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you very much for your help. You were right. I redeployed the entire site to the server and everything worked. Strange that it didn't work on the server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<x-navbar>` will look for a Blade component named `Navbar` in a file named `Navbar.php`.

Unfortunately, Windows is case insensitive, but Linux is not. Naming the file `navbar.php` and the class `navbar` will work on Windows, but fail when deployed to a Linux webhost. (PHP's classes are case-insensitive, so `navbar`, `Navbar`, or `nAvBaR` will all work, but the Composer autoloader's file paths are case-sensitive if on a case-sensitive system.)

When working with Laravel, it's important to follow [their coding style](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/contributions#coding-style) to avoid this issue; Laravel expects classes to use PascalCase and for file names to match. [Laravel Pint](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pint) can automatically resolve these and other such issues for you.